# Sum of floating point values in array in php

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

```
$gtz="select * from add_to_cart where user_id='$userid'";
$gz1=mysql_query($gtz);

 while($gz2=mysql_fetch_array($gz1))
 {




    $tprcz[]=$gz2['total_price'];

 }

$fullquantityz=array_sum($tqtyz);
```

The $tprcz[] returns floating point values( Eg 2.00 & 4.00 ).But when the sum is found $fullquantityz returns the value as integer and not as floating point 
ie  2.00 + 4.00 = 6   ,I want the value to be printed as 2.00 + 4.00 = 6.00

Comment: off topic: be warned that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. It is recommended to switch to a different api -- either the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Answer (score 0):

Please ref link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php , which will give you code to format your number.

Answer (score 0):

Try number_format($fullquantityz,2)

Answer (score 0):

```
return number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return sprintf('%.2f',$fullquantityz);
```